# $post->post_meta not pulling any post in wordpress/php

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta

I have a function in php as shown below:

```
function hello_world( $post ) {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($post); echo '</pre>'; // Line A
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($post->post_meta); echo '</pre>'; // Line B
    return $post->post_meta;
}
```

I have added `Line A` and `Line B` in the function above for debugging purposes. In the function `hello_world` above, `Line A` returns list of all posts whereeas Line B doesn't return anything.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the wordpress or php code above so that `Line B` returns list of posts.

**Edit 1:**

Added code for `$loc_query`

```
function area_search( $abc ) {
        if ( $abc ) {
            $loc_query = new \WP_Query( [
                's'           => $abc,
                'post_type'   => 'abc-xyz',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            ] );
        } else {
            $loc_query = new \WP_Query( [
                'post_type'   => 'abc-xyz',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'ep_integrate' => true,
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order'   => 'ASC',
            ] );
        }
        $result = array_map( __NAMESPACE__ . '\hello_world', $query->posts );
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>'; // Line A
        return group( $result );
    }
```

Comment: How you are calling the function?

Comment: like this `$result = array_map( __NAMESPACE__ . '\hello_world', $loc_query->posts );`

Comment: `$loc_query->posts` isn't it it self an array or post objects? The way your code the function you have to pass a single post object but I assure you are passing an array of objects

Comment: `$loc_query->posts` is an array of posts. Yes. I am passing an array of objects.

Comment: The above code works perfectly fine in production environment but it doesn't work in development environment so I guess something is missing in development environment.

Comment: If it's an array of object then you must run a loop to the the meta. I'll provide an example bellow. You can use that.

Comment: Yes, I will have a look but I am wondering why everything is working fine in the production environment in comparison to the development environment.

Comment: Your production site must have different code. Coz the code logically shouldn't work as the way is used.

Comment: I compared branches and they both have the same code.

Comment: can you share the code of `$loc_query` and the arguments ?

Comment: @SabbirHasan I have updated my code.

Comment: I want to mention one thing again that I am using the same code in production environment and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: It's very unusual to see `$post->post_meta`, that's not how you should be retrieving post meta. Use `get_post_meta`

Comment: like this  `$post->get_post_meta` ?

Comment: No, `get_post_meta` is a function, it isn't a method on the post object. I've just looked at your edit and you don't use a normal post loop, call none of the standard loop functions, and appear to be directly using the internals of `WP_Query`, all very unusual. What exactly are you trying to do that required this code? This looks like an X Y question, where you asked how to implement your solution, when you should have asked how to solve your problem

Comment: Also why do you declare the query twice? Wouldn't it be simpler to declare the arguments then replace them in the conditional?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is interfering with the internal structure of `WP_Query` and `WP_Post`, and making assumptions about how it works. This is extremely unusual, and not best practice when developing with WordPress.

Case in point, officially there is no `post_meta` member variable on that class ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/ ). That's not how you fetch a posts meta key/values.

**Instead, use a standard post loop, and standard API calls.**

Here's what a standard `WP_Query` post loop should look like:

```php
$args = [
    // parameters go here
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // display the post
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo "no posts were found";
}
```

Note that a standard post loop lifecycle happens, as well as all the expected hooks. You can do work inside the `while` loop for each post. For example, fetching all the post meta. To do that, use the `get_post_meta` function:

```php
$all_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
```

It might be tempting to think that a `WP_Post` object follows the naive OO dream of an all encompassing API for posts, a one-stop representation of a single post and all the things that there is to know and can be done about it. But in reality it's a data container. You won't find class methods or methods of sub-classing it.

Additionally, by poking around and directly accessing the internal data structures, you bypass a lot of functionality and risk your code being broken in the future. For example post meta gets fetched in advance and stored in `WP_Cache` to avoid query duplication. There are also filters that allow plugins and other code opportuniities to make changes or fix things.